# 'Bot' object has no attribute 'set_proxy'

Tags: python

I have been using these lines of code. But this error appeared
'Bot' object has no attribute 'set_proxy'
I have tried to use it without proxy but then I got this error `ERROR - Request returns 429 error!`

```
from instabot import Bot
import time

def unfollow_users(username, password, users_to_unfollow, unfollow_interval=60, proxy=None):
    bot = Bot()
    
    # Set proxy if provided
    if proxy:
        bot.set_proxy(proxy)
    
    bot.login(username=username, password=password)

    for user_to_unfollow in users_to_unfollow:
        user_id = bot.get_user_id_from_username(user_to_unfollow)
        if user_id:
            bot.unfollow(user_id)
            print(f"Unfollowed {user_to_unfollow}")
            time.sleep(unfollow_interval)
        else:
            print(f"User {user_to_unfollow} not found")

    bot.logout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Your Instagram credentials
    instagram_username = 'usernm'
    instagram_password = 'pass'

    # List of usernames to unfollow
    users_to_unfollow = ["user1id", "user2id", "user3id"]

    # Time interval between unfollow actions (in seconds)
    unfollow_interval_seconds = 60

    # Proxy configuration (replace with your actual proxy details)
    proxy_config = {
        'http': 'http://212.193.137.206:62740:NReJKktP:vjTr2QJC',
        'https': 'https://185.81.71.172:63310:NReJKktP:vjTr2QJC',
    }

    # Call the function to unfollow users with proxy support
    unfollow_users(instagram_username, instagram_password, users_to_unfollow, unfollow_interval_seconds, proxy_config)
```

TERMINAL RESULT:

```
PS D:\instagram unfollow> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "d:/instagram unfollow/main.py"
2024-01-15 18:38:00,316 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\instagram unfollow\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    unfollow_users(instagram_username, instagram_password, users_to_unfollow, unfollow_interval_seconds, proxy_config)
  File "d:\instagram unfollow\main.py", line 9, in unfollow_users
    bot.set_proxy(proxy)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'set_proxy'
```

I have installed PIP and everything needed(BTW my python version is 3.11.4)

Comment: As the error says there really is no `set_proxy` method on the `Bot` instance...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat So? How do I set proxy then?

Comment: The `login` method has a proxy argument from what I understand. BTW that library that you are using seems unmaintained.

Answer (score 2):

Your python version is 3.11.4 but the stable release of `instabot` currently supports Python 2.7, 3.5 - 3.7. You may need to downgrade your python version.

Please keep your current python version and also install a supported version. Then use a virtual environment to manage this project. For example, you can use a python 3.7 virtual environment for this project after installing python 3.7 in your system.

Then you can `pip install instabot` in your virtual environment. See [Project description](https://pypi.org/project/instabot/).

Comment: But what if really set_proxy method does not exist. How do I check that. Actually adding proxy was my friends idea and he add these extra lines but he is gone to somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you should try first with a supported python version and see if you encounter this problem.